# VMware tools installer error on Windows 2000 guest: "Setup was unable to upgrade the Windows Installer."

Tags: virtual-machine, vmware, windows-installer, windows-2000, vmware-tools

I am trying to install VMware tools on a Windows 2000 Guest machine. However, when I run the setup, I get the following error:

> Setup was unable to upgrade the Windows Installer.

I am using VMware 9.0.2 build-1031769 (from Help>About).
How do I avoid this problem?

Comment: Has the Win2K guest been updated to SP4 + all following rollups/updates (including Windows Installer updates)?

Comment: Sounds like you will be unable to install the tools because the installer used isn't supported by Windows 2000.  I would contact VMWare about this problem.

Comment: @techie007 no it's not sp4, updating it to sp4 now see if that works

Comment: @techie007 updated to sp4 and restarted the vm, will it work...

Comment: startup sound, disk in, vmware tools installer opened, ERROR! but we are lucky, there is a KB article on it. KB835732.

Comment: and the error changed too. MS runtime dlls cannot be installed on the system.

Comment: downloading the extra update...

Comment: done! rebooting...

Comment: http://kb.vmware.com/selfservice/microsites/search.do?language=en_US&cmd=displayKC&externalId=2007120 if you didn't see it already. :)

Comment: went to bed so i had to suspend, back now, tools disk in, and...

Answer (score -1):

Solution was to install SP4 and the KB835732 update. Then install the tools and problem solved.